# Bug: biblatex can not deal name prefix like "van der ", Miktex updated on 2016.01.16

Tags: biblatex, debugging

Firstly, hello everyone. I am new here : )

I am writing my phd thesis using MikTeX + TeXnicCenter and everything goes well, until I have updated MikTeX today.

**My Problem:**

The program gives an error message to the "same old" command:

```
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers={},notkeyword={Eigene}, notkeyword={Datenblatt},
title={Fremdliteratur}, heading=subbibliography]
```

The error message looks like this:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...nameprefix {van~der}\isdot }\ifprefchar
```

**Investigation**

I have found out that this error comes from the name prefix "van der". If I write them together without space in `*.bib` file and compile it, it works again.

What's the best way to fix this or work around it? Is it a bug?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add an example of a bib entry that produces the error?

Comment: Preferably a complete, small document as well. Have you written `nameprfix{van-der}` somewhere rather than `nameprefix{van-der}`? (just a guess.)

Comment: I have solved the problem now by writing the family name in *.bib file in {} like {van der XXX}. This helps.

Comment: Can you provide a full example that reproduces the issue (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864))? I did some checks based on your post here and couldn't reproduce the problem. As cfr noticed the problem seems to be that the command `\nameprfix` is called, but it should be `\nameprefix`. The bug does not occur in the newest version of `biblatex`, maybe an update can help you.

Comment: If you are using BibTeX you might be experiencing [bug #365](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/365), the issue is known and has been resolved in the development version, a fix will be included in the next release to CTAN.

Comment: Why do you use the programm `bibtex` for sorting? It makes much more sense to use `backend=biber` which is the default and will give no error.

Answer (score 10):

> The bug has been fixed in version 3.3 of `biblatex`. If at all possible, please update `biblatex`.

The following MWE reproduces the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\nocite{vangennep}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

one gets

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> ...nameprefix {van}\isdot }\ifprefchar 
>                                                   {}{\bibnamedelimc }
> ```

which tells us that `\ifprefchar` is undefined.

---

This command was added in `biblatex` 3.2, but it was neglected to add the command to the BibTeX-backend file `biblatex1.sty`.
This problem is known ([#365 at github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/365)) and has been resolved.

Thus the problem only occurs when using BibTeX as back-end. If you use Biber, everything works fine. (In most cases it is recommended to use Biber anyway, so it might be worth thinking about switching.)

In the meantime the lines

```
\newcommand{\ifprefchar}{\ifpunctmark{'}}
```

should restore functionality with BibTeX as a work-around while you wait for the next release.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand{\ifprefchar}{\ifpunctmark{'}}

\nocite{vangennep}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just repeat the [comment from Buwei Zhang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287942/bug-biblatex-can-not-deal-name-prefix-like-van-der-miktex-updated-on-2016-0#comment696540_287942) that it is a completely sufficient solution to enclose the full surname in curly brackets in the `.bib` file:

```
author = "Julius Ceasar and Harry {van de Mond}",
```

This solution works well with `biblatex`, which has its reasons compared to `biber`, and no additional command is nescessary, allowing for easy applicability of the bibliography also in other documents.

Comment: Of course this destroys the name parsing when it comes to the prefixes as now "van de Mond" is regarded as the last name and not only "Mond" as last name and "van de" as prefixes. In German bibliographies that might be undesirable (often you give people as "Zanden, Johanna von"). Seeing that the fix is contained in the current version of `biblatex`, I don't see the point in advocating this idea.