# How to find the correct bibtex item from the reference we have?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Here are my file contents for my bib file.

```
@Book{bapat2013combinatorial,
 author = {Bapat, R. B.},
 title = {Combinatorial matrix theory and generalized inverses of matrices},
 publisher = {Springer},
 year = {2013},
 address = {New Delhi New York},
 isbn = {8132210522}
 }
 @article{moore1935general,
   title={General analysis},
   author={Moore, Eliakim Hastings},
   year={1935}
 }
@article{berman2003completelypositive,
    author  = Berman, A. and Shaked-Monderer, N,
    title   = "Completely Positive Matrices",
    journal = "Singapore: World Scientific",
    year    = "2003",
    page ={69–70}
}

 @article{dickinson2011geometry,
   title={Geometry of the copositive and completely positive cones},
   author={Dickinson, Peter JC},
   journal={Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications},
   volume={380},
   number={1},
   pages={377--395},
   year={2011},
   publisher={Elsevier}
 }
 @article{drew1994completely,
   title={Completely positive matrices associated with M-matrices},
   author={Drew, John H and Johnson, Charles R and Loewy, Raphael},
   journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
   volume={37},
   number={4},
   pages={303--310},
   year={1994},
   publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
 }


@inproceedings{rao1972generalized,
    title={Generalized inverse of a matrix and its applications},
    author={Rao, C Radhakrishna and Mitra, Sujit Kumar and others},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the sixth Berkeley symposium on mathematical statistics and probability},
    volume={1},
    pages={601--620},
    year={1972}
  }

 @article{mason2007linear,
   title={On linear copositive Lyapunov functions and the stability of switched positive linear systems},
   author={Mason, Oliver and Shorten, Robert},
   journal={IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control},
   volume={52},
   number={7},
   pages={1346--1349},
   year={2007},
   publisher={IEEE}
 }

 @article{berman2012characterisation,
   title={A characterisation of common diagonal stability over cones},
   author={Berman, Abraham and King, Christopher and Shorten, Robert},
   journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
   volume={60},
   number={10},
   pages={1117--1123},
   year={2012},
   publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
 }

 @article{campbell1976applications,
   title={Applications of the Drazin inverse to linear systems of differential equations with singular constant coefficients},
   author={Campbell, Stephen L and Meyer, Jr, Carl D and Rose, Nicholas J},
   journal={SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics},
   volume={31},
   number={3},
   pages={411--425},
   year={1976},
   publisher={SIAM}
 }
 @article{rao1955analysis,
   title={Analysis of dispersion for multiply classified data with unequal numbers in cells},
   author={Rao, C Radhakrishna},
   journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics},
   pages={253--280},
   year={1955},
   publisher={JSTOR}
 }

 @article{mitra1968generalised,
   title={On a generalised inverse of a matrix and applications},
   author={Mitra, Sujit Kumar},
   journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A},
   pages={107--114},
   year={1968},
   publisher={JSTOR}
 }

 @article{mitra1968new,
   title={A new class of g-inverse of square matrices},
   author={Mitra, Sujit Kumar},
   journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A},
   pages={323--330},
   year={1968},
   publisher={JSTOR}
 }

 @article{bhimasankaram1969theorem,
   title={On a theorem of Rao on g-inverses of matrices},
   author={Bhimasankaram, P},
   journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A},
   pages={365--368},
   year={1969},
   publisher={JSTOR}
 }

@article{mitra1970some,
  title={Some results on idempotent matrices and a matrix equation connected with the distribution of quadratic forms},
  author={Mitra, Sujit Kumar and Bhimasankaram, P},
  journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A},
  pages={353--356},
  year={1970},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

 @article{mitra1968simultaneous,
   title={Simultaneous reduction of a pair of quadratic forms},
   author={Mitra, Sujit K and Rao, C Radhakrishna},
   journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A},
   pages={313--322},
   year={1968},
   publisher={JSTOR}
 }

 @article{mitra1968some,
   title={Some results in estimation and tests of linear hypotheses under the Gauss-Markoff model},
   author={Mitra, Sujit K and Rao, C Radhakrishna},
   journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A},
   pages={281--290},
   year={1968},
   publisher={JSTOR}
 }

 @article{mitra1969conditions,
   title={Conditions for optimality and validity of simple least squares theory},
   author={Mitra, Sujit Kumar and Rao, C Radhakrishna},
   journal={Annals of Mathematical Statistics},
   volume={40},
   number={5},
   pages={1617--1624},
   year={1969},
   publisher={Institute of Mathematical Statistics}
 }

 @article{rao1968note,
   title={A note on a previous lemma in the theory of least squares and some further results},
   author={Rao, C Radhakrishna},
   journal={Sankhy{\=a}: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A},
   pages={259--266},
   year={1968},
   publisher={JSTOR}
 }

 @article{moore1920abstract,
   title={Abstract},
   author={Moore, EH},
   journal={Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society},
   volume={26},
   number={394-395},
   pages={38},
   year={1920}
 }


 @article{meyer1975role,
   title={The role of the group generalized inverse in the theory of finite Markov chains},
   author={Meyer, Jr, Carl D},
   journal={Siam Review},
   volume={17},
   number={3},
   pages={443--464},
   year={1975},
   publisher={SIAM}
 }


 @inproceedings{penrose1955generalized,
    title={A generalized inverse for matrices},
    author={Penrose, Roger},
    booktitle={Mathematical proceedings of the Cambridge philosophical society},
    volume={51},
    number={03},
    pages={406--413},
    year={1955},
    organization={Cambridge Univ Press}
  }

 @book{luenberger1997optimization,
   title={Optimization by Vector Space Methods},
   author={Luenberger, D.G.},
   isbn={9780471181170},
   lccn={68008716},
   series={Professional Series},
   url={https://books.google.fr/books?id=lZU0CAH4RccC},
   year={1997},
   publisher={Wiley}
 }
@book{nashed1976generalized,
  title={Generalized Inverses and Applications: Proceedings of an Advanced Seminar on Generalized Inverses and Applications},
  author={Nashed, M.Z.},
  series={Academic Press rapid manuscript reproduction},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
  year={1976},
  publisher={Academic Press}
} 

@book{kesavan2014functional,
  title={Functional Analysis},
  author={Kesavan, S.},
  series={Texts and Readings in Mathematics},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
    year={2014},
  publisher={Hindustan Book Agency(India)}
  Number={52}
  isbn={978-93-80250-62-5}
} 

@article{mos,
author = {Moslehian},
title = {A Survey Of The Complemented Subspace Problem},
journal = {Trends in Mathematics,
Information Center for Mathematical Sciences},
year = {June, 2006},
volume = {9}
Number = {1}
Pages={91–98},
note = {tohbhhjhj appear},
}

@article{stocia,
author = {Stoica, P., Jakobsson, A., and Li, J.},
title = { Matrix Optimization Result with DSP Applications},
journal = {Digital Signal Processing},
year = {1996},
volume = {6}
Number = {1}
Pages={195–201},
note = {tohbhhjhj appear},
}



@article{pappas1,
  title={Minimization of constrained quadratic forms in Hilbert spaces},
  author={Pappas, Dimitrios and others},
  journal={Ann. Funct. Anal},
  volume={2},
  number={1},
  pages={1--12},
  year={2011}
}
@article{pappas2013restricted,
  title={Restricted linear constrained minimization of quadratic functionals},
  author={Pappas, Dimitrios},
  journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
  volume={61},
  number={10},
  pages={1394--1407},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{stanimirovic2014minimization,
  title={Minimization of quadratic forms using the Drazin-inverse solution},
  author={Stanimirovi{\'c}, Predrag S and Pappas, Dimitrios and Miljkovi{\'c}, Sladjana},
  journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
  volume={62},
  number={2},
  pages={252--266},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{ben1963generalized,
  title={Generalized inverses and the Bott-Duffin network analysis},
  author={Ben-Israel, A and Charnes, A},
  journal={Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications},
  volume={7},
  number={3},
  pages={428--435},
  year={1963},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{hakimi1969generalized,
  title={The generalized inverse in network analysis and quadratic error-minimization problems},
  author={Hakimi, S},
  journal={Circuit Theory, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={16},
  number={4},
  pages={559--562},
  year={1969},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{manjunatha2014core,
  title={Core--EP inverse},
  author={Manjunatha Prasad, K and Mohana, KS},
  journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
  volume={62},
  number={6},
  pages={792--802},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}


@book{Gorokhov,
author = {P.Stoica, Gorokhov.A.},
title = {Generalized quadratic minimization and a signal processing application},
series = {Signal Processing Conference (EUSIPCO 1998), 9th European },
year = {8-11 Sept. 1998 },
Publisher ={IEEE},
Pages={1 - 4 },
note = {tohbhhjhj appear},
}

@book{ben1974generalized,
  title={Generalized Inverses: Theory and Applications},
  author={Ben-Israel, A. and Greville, T.N.E.},
  isbn={9780387002934},
  lccn={73023078},
  series={A Wiley -Intersciences Series of Texts},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=o3-97W8vCdIC},
  year={1974},
  publisher={Wiley}
}

@Book{rudin2013principles,
 author = {Rudin, Walter},
 title = {Principles of mathematical analysis},
 publisher = {McGraw-Hill Education (India) Private Limited},
 year = {2013},
 address = {New Delhi},
 isbn = {9781259064784}
 }

 @Book{lang2002algebra,
  author = {Lang, Serge},
  title = {Algebra},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {2002},
  address = {New York},
  isbn = {9780387953854}
  }
@book{jacobson1985basic,
  title={Basic Algebra},
  author={Jacobson, N.},
  number={v. 1},
  isbn={9780716714804},
  lccn={84025836},
  series={Basic Algebra},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-G0PAQAAMAAJ},
  year={1985},
  publisher={W.H. Freeman}
}

@article{gray1980nonnegative,
  title={Nonnegative factorization of positive semidefinite nonnegative matrices},
  author={Gray, Leonard J and Wilson, David G},
  journal={Linear algebra and its applications},
  volume={31},
  pages={119--127},
  year={1980},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@book{taylor-func,
 author = {Taylor, Angus Ellis and Lay, David C.},
 title = {Introduction to Functional Analysis, 2Nd Ed.},
 year = {1986},
 isbn = {0898749514},
 publisher = {Krieger Publishing Co., Inc.},
 address = {Melbourne, FL, USA},
} 


@article{plemmons1972generalized,
  title={The generalized inverse of a nonnegative matrix},
  author={Plemmons, RJ and Cline, RE},
  journal={Proceedings of the american mathematical society},
  pages={46--50},
  year={1972},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{debreu1953nonnegative,
  title={Nonnegative square matrices},
  author={Debreu, Gerard and Herstein, Israel Nathan},
  journal={Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society},
  pages={597--607},
  year={1953},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{berman1974inverses,
  title={Inverses of nonnegative matrices},
  author={Berman, Abraham and Plemmons, Robert J},
  journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
  volume={2},
  number={2},
  pages={161--172},
  year={1974},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@book{collatz2014functional,
  title={Functional analysis and numerical mathematics},
  author={Collatz, Lothar},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Academic Press}
}

@article{dong2006methods,
  title={Methods for constrained optimization},
  author={Dong, Shuonan},
  journal={Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Massachusetts},
  year={2006}
}

@article{elhashash2008generalizations,
  title={Generalizations of M-matrices which may not have a nonnegative inverse},
  author={Elhashash, Abed and Szyld, Daniel B},
  journal={Linear Algebra and its Applications},
  volume={429},
  number={10},
  pages={2435--2450},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@book{bapat1997nonnegative,
  title={Nonnegative matrices and applications},
  author={Bapat, Ravi B and Raghavan, Tirukkannamangai ES},
  volume={64},
  year={1997},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
@article{bapat1998algebraic,
  title={Algebraic connectivity and the characteristic set of a graph},
  author={Bapat, RB and Pati, Sukanta},
  journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
  volume={45},
  number={2-3},
  pages={247--273},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@article{kirkland1996characteristic,
  title={Characteristic vertices of weighted trees via Perron values},
  author={Kirkland, Steve and Neumann, Michael and Shader, Bryan L},
  journal={Linear and Multilinear Algebra},
  volume={40},
  number={4},
  pages={311--325},
  year={1996},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@article{berman2015open,
  title={Open problems in the theory of completely positive and copositive matrices},
  author={Berman, Avi and Dur, Mirjam and Shaked-Monderer, Naomi},
  journal={Electronic Journal of Linear Algebra},
  volume={29},
  number={1},
  pages={46--58},
  year={2015}
}

@article{murty1987some,
  title={Some NP-complete problems in quadratic and nonlinear programming},
  author={Murty, Katta G and Kabadi, Santosh N},
  journal={Mathematical programming},
  volume={39},
  number={2},
  pages={117--129},
  year={1987},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@phdthesis{manideepathesis,
    title    = {On Nonnegative Matrices and
    Generalized $M-$matrices},
    school   = {Indian Institute of Technology Guwahati},
    author   = {Manideepa Saha},
    year     = {2013}, %other attributes omitted
}

 @inproceedings{ding2005equivalence,
   title={On the Equivalence of Nonnegative Matrix Factorization and Spectral Clustering.},
   author={Ding, Chris HQ and He, Xiaofeng and Simon, Horst D},
   booktitle={SDM},
   volume={5},
   pages={606--610},
   year={2005},
   organization={SIAM}
 }
```

I wrongly or mistakenly cited one item from this list.

That is showing like this in my reference.

[image]

How can I find: which is the correct bibitem corresponding to the number [2] in my reference list.

I am using biblatex for bibliography and article class.

here are my codes to print bibliography:

In preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
}
```

And in the document:

```
\printbibliography [title=Works cited,category=cited]
```

### Note:

I couldnot find this citation in my pdf file anywhere.

Help me to find this file.

Sorry, I am not giving MWE, because of the data I am having is quite large.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `\nocite{*}` will print all items from `bib` file.

Comment: David, how many entries have you cited so far?

Comment: It seems that almost every entry in your database is faulty, you have to fix them. 5 minutes into fixing stuff and i still don't see what you show us. EDIT: Everything corrected, still can't reproduce. Please show a MWE.

Comment: don't you get a tex error processing your document corresponding to that failed reference? (also `\nocite{*}` is useful for debugging your bib file but it wouldn't normally be used in a real docuemnt)

Comment: Your `.bib` entries do have quite some issues. What I can tell you that [2] is very likely an `@article` and one that is missing the `journal(title)` field. Maybe you can have a look at the `.blg` file, maybe that can give you some hints about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.bib` file contains several errors, but luckily BibTeX assists you in finding them, have a look at the `.blg` file and fix the problems (mostly missing braces around field contents, missing commas after fields and wrong name formats).

---

If your document compiles correctly, you can check who is who in the bibliography with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{entrykey}{\ttfamily[#1]}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printfield{entrykey}\setunit{\addspace}}
```

this prints the `entrykey` at the beginning of all entries.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{entrykey}{\ttfamily[#1]}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printfield{entrykey}\setunit{\addspace}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,geer,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi moewe, running your example, i get the same error reported in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/1Rd8HwHV7FA with `2015/12/22 v3.2`.

Comment: Seems that `\ifprefchar` is new, not simply renamed. used in `biblatex.def`, defined in `biblatex2.sty` but missing in `biblatex1.sty`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, we might have missed something in v3.2, the issue is known https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/365 and has been resolved in the DEV version. Interestingly, I didn't get that error here, but it appears from time to time for people (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287942/35864) unconfirmed).

Comment: Just saw it :-)

Comment: Did you use the DEV version, since you get no error.

Comment: @Johannes_B I didn't at first, actually, and just checked that indeed `\ifprefchar` *is* undefined. But now I get the error as well ...

Comment: But as always, using `biber` solves that issue ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, it does, though in this case it really was a bug with the code in `biblatex1.sty` (it was simply forgotten to copy the code from `biblatex2.sty` to `biblatex1.sty`). What keeps me wondering is the elusive nature of the issue: when I created the MWE above I worked from an existing document and had no problem, but when I copied the code to a fresh document I immediately got the error.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have that def in `biblatex.def` which is shared by both?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm not sure, I haven't gotten to grips with all design decisions. Fact is that the definitions in `biblatex.def` are often more "tame" than those in the `.sty`s; but there is indeed some redundancy between `biblatex1.sty` and `biblatex2.sty`.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but :-) http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/16101/biblatex-kombination-bibstyleauthoryear-und-citestylealphabetic

Comment: `biblatex1.sty` is mostly "frozen" apart from the odd change so I sometimes forget about it ... there is redundancy in some cases due to things that happened before the major changes for biblatex 2.0 which were all `biber` related. At that point it was clear that one `biblatex.sty` for both `bibtex` and `biber` would be a confusing mass of conditionals.