# Biblatex - Undefined control sequence with specific source

Tags: biblatex

As soon as I try to cite a specific source, the bibliography causes an "Undefined control sequence" error. When I cite a different source, no problems occur.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew, backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex} % chem-angew
\addbibresource{literature.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{Maitlis.2013a}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The specific entry from the bib-file:

```
@Book{Maitlis.2013a,
  title =     {Greener Fischer-Tropsch Processes for Fuels and Feedstocks},
  date =      {2013},
  editor =    {Maitlis, Peter M. and de Klerk, A.},
  publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag},
  location =  {Weinheim},
  file =      {Maitlis.2013a.pdf:Books\\Maitlis.2013a.pdf:PDF},
  keywords =  {Fischer-Tropsch}
}
```

This is the output from the log-file:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ibnameprefix {de}\isdot \ifprefchar 
                                              {} {} {\ifuseprefix {\bibn...
l.10
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue? Have I missed something? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This a known bug (and resolved in the dev) for the bibtex backend. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/365

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Bug: biblatex can not deal name prefix like “van der”, Miktex updated on 2016.01.16](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287942/35864). Would you mind us closing it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would post it as a comment but I don't have enough reputation. What I've seen is that if you change the backend to biber (from bibtek) you don't get any error. This code in fact compiles:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=chem-angew, backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex} % chem-angew
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{Maitlis.2013a}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you don't need bibtex as a backend I would suggest to go with biber (also suggested by sharelatex).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot go with biber, as the group policy on the computer I am working on, prohibits me from running an external program. And as biber is called from some temporary cache folder, it is not working.

Comment: @Dieter: You can try to set an environment variable which will tell biber to unpack itself in some other folder: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the same that this post. It comes from the name.

[Bug: biblatex can not deal name prefix like "van der ", Miktex updated on 2016.01.16](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287942/bug-biblatex-can-not-deal-name-prefix-like-van-der-miktex-updated-on-2016-0)

(I also not have enough reputation to comment, sorry)