# Undefined control sequence because of "de" in the author names

Tags: biblatex, mactex

I updated my Latex files (I am using MacTex2015 distribution) and since than I am getting a strange undefined control sequence error. Bibliographical entries that have "de" in the author name don't work unless I change it to "De" which is wrong.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{devogel1967,
    Address = {Leiden},
    Author = {Cornelia Johanna de Vogel},
    Call-Number = {TH: Ps 2.276},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-20 14:47:36 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-17 10:23:51 +0000},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Number = {3. The Helenistic-Roman Period},
    Publisher = {Brill Archive},
    Title = {Greek Philosophy},
    Year = {1967}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite{devogel1967}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Can someone help with this? Thank you!

Comment: I have no error with `backend=biber`

Comment: FYI, the best format to make sure that bibtex/biblatex recognizes correctly name and surname is `Author = {de Vogel, Cornelia Johanna}`. I wouldn't bet on bibtex parsing that name correctly in the current form.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - setting the author field to `Author = {de Vogel, Cornelia Johanna}` does *not* help. I doubt BibTeX is to blame here; more likely, it's a bug in `biblatex`'s handling of the output produced by BibTeX.

Comment: Author = {de Vogel, Cornelia Johanna} also produces an error

Comment: I have no error with bibtex or biber with your MWE. What version of biblatex are you using?

Comment: Yes I realise bibtex or biber are fine but I am using biblatex. My version is 3.2 (the newest version).

Comment: @PLK: I don't think that the version with the correction of https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/365 found its way into texlive.

Comment: How can I manually update MacTex2015 to get that version?

Comment: I'm pretty confident that you are facing the error described in [Bug: biblatex can not deal name prefix like “van der ”, Miktex updated on 2016.01.16](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287942/35864). The problem is known and will be resolved with the next update, see the answer in the other question for a work-around.

Comment: BTW: You probably don't want to abuse the `number` field in the way you do. You could use `volume` and `maintitle` instead: `@book{devogel1967,
  address = {Leiden},
  author = {Cornelia Johanna de Vogel},
  publisher = {Brill Archive},
  maintitle = {Greek Philosophy},
  mainsubtitle = {A Collection of Texts},
  title = {The Hellenistic-Roman Period},
  volume = {3},
  year = {1967},
}`

Comment: Ah, ok. You can download biblatex 3.3 from the sourceforge project development folder and install manually, just unpack the tds version in your local texmf tree and run "sudo texhash". If you want to use biber, you'll also need the 2.4 development version, also from Sourceforge.